# I am trying to setup a Node.js FTP Server that can pull data from another FTP server

Tags: node.js, ssl, ftp

Rule:

Node.js Server will pull data from another FTP server retrieving a .csv file.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
```

The code is as follows:

```
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");

(async function () {
  const client = new ftp.Client();
  client.ftp.verbose = true;
  try {
    await client.access({
      host: "host",
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      secure: true,
      strictSSL: false,
    });
    console.log(await client.list());
    await client.uploadFrom("VEHICLES.csv");
    await client.downloadTo("VEHICLES.csv");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  client.close();
})();
```

A beer to whoever can help me out..

**UPDATE**

add in .access options:

```
secureOptions: {
   rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

Comment: I cannot see this `strictSSL` option documented anywhere. Are you sure it exists? Anyway, the client fails to validate the server certificate.

Comment: I’m pretty new to FTP server setups, but just to clarify I need to setup an SSL or some sort of certificate on my Node app so that the server can verify the data being sent over FTPS? Depending on the type of connection be it passive or active?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with passive vs. active. It is simply that the certificate of the FTP server you access cannot be validated.